# How can I find a given value exists in javascript array using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, javascript-framework

I want to know whether the given value exists in javascript array or not.

Here is my case,

```
var array = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
         {'id': 2, 'name': 'yyy'},
         {'id': 3, 'name': 'zzz'}];

 var searchValue = {'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'};
```

I tried the following,

```
var exists = _.where(array, {name: 'xxx'});
```

It return the obj `{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'}`. It works as expect.

Here I need to check `exists.length > 0` to find whether it exists or not

But is there any other function of get the same.

Since if the function return `true` if exists and `false` if not, It would be better.

Comment: Can't you simply do `_.where(array, {name: 'xxx'}).length > 0`

Comment: @Satpal: `_.where` has to find them all, `_.find` and `_.findWhere` will short-circuit and return as soon as they've found a match so they're more appropriate for existence checks.

Answer (score 9):

It's the same idea, but would this do the trick ?

```
return !!_.findWhere(array, {name : 'xxx'});
```

Otherwise (but slighly longer)

```
return _.some(array, function (item) {
   return (item.name === "xxx");
});
```

Also, note that _.where and _.findWhere seems to be on the [deprecation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/1162) row ... And that as @Juzer Ali pointed out, you might not even need it if you're targeting modern enough browsers.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use underscore. These days browsers have these idioms built in. See [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
array.some(function(elem){
    return !!elem["name"] === "xxx";
});
```

From the docs

> some does not mutate the array on which it is called.

Comment: Let's precise it doesn't work on IE8 because the main reason to use a library like underscore is precisely to be able to use modern functions on IE8-.

Comment: Wouldn't this return true if any element has an 'xxx' property ? I think the OP wants to check the value...

Comment: OP asked >  (if) the function return true if exists and false if not, It would be better.

Comment: Yes, but I understood that as saying "I need a function that returns true or false", instead of "having a function that returns a list, and having to check the size of the list" ; but "exists" means "is an element with the name I want".

Comment: @phtrivier, Oops, thats what happens when you type faster than you think. I corrected my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @dystroy: Your concerns are correct. Let this answer serve as a promotion of built in capabilities of ECMAScript 5, thus moving slowly away from including unnecessary libraries. I think a polyfill should exist which can provide this same API in older browsers. Any1 interested in writing one?

Answer (score 1):

Use [***isEmpty***](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty)

```
var exists = !_.isEmpty(_.where(array, {name: 'xxx'}));
```

**[*Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/SHmZw/)**